# Provide error response type to `useFetch()` in Nuxt 3 for POST method

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, fetch-api, typescript-generics, nuxt3

I'd like to provide a type of the error response to useFetch in Nuxt 3, however, when I add the type, typescript starts screaming at me that "POST" is not assignable to method.
This is what I tried:

```js
useFetch<void, ApiResponseError>(this.url, {
            method: 'POST',
            body: data,
            headers: this.headers,
            onResponseError: this.transformError
        })
```

How could I do it?
Is that possible?

Comment: Based on your question, it is something similar to this(If I am not mistaken). 
https://ibb.co/r6FK3gj

In my case, the issue was because I renamed the file and for some reasons it did not update the `InternalApi interface` inside the nitro.d.ts file. The work around was to update it and restart the app. https://ibb.co/fk2rJVr

I am not sure if my issue is the same as yours but try checking the `nitro.d.ts` file and make sure that the route is correct.

Comment: Hi, I do not have a problem with regular `method: 'POST'`. My issue comes up whenever I try to provide a type for the error generic. In your example, you don't do that. It only happens when I use `useFetch<void, ApiResponseError>` and the issue persists after I restart the dev server.

Comment: There is an open issue on Github about this : 
https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt/issues/19077